# artifactory-maven-plugin: How to resolve dependencies from private Artifactory without settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

How can I configure the artifactory-maven-plugin to resolve dependencies from our private Artifactory server?

The official documentation explains on how to publish:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin#MavenArtifactoryPlugin-Usage

Usually, dependency resolving works by adding servers to my .m2/settings.xml and specifying credentials there. However, in a cloud Docker build environment, it is difficult to place the settings.xml inside the container. It would be much easier if the plugin could be configured accordingly.

The Gradle Artifactory Plugin has explicit documentation about this (see dependencies resolution):
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin#GradleArtifactoryPlugin-UsingtheArtifactoryPluginDSL

Turns out the Maven plugin also has a resolver configuration option. But it is not documented anywhere. This does not work (Maven still won't try to download dependencies from Artifactory):

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <resolver>
                        <contextUrl>${artifactory.context.url}</contextUrl>
                        <username>${artifactory.username}</username>
                        <password>${artifactory.password}</password>
                        <repoKey>libs-local</repoKey>
                    </resolver>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Maven to resolve artifacts through Artifactory you need to modify the settings.xml. You can generate one automatically, or modify it manually.

jfrog docs has provided steps to do this ,

> In the Artifact Repository Browser of the Artifacts module, select Set Me Up. In the Set Me Up dialog, set Maven in the Tool field and click "Generate Maven Settings". You can now specify the repositories you want to configure for Maven.

Check [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository)

Comment: Yes, but that is the problem. I need to transfer this settings.xml into my docker container, which runs in a cloud environment. It is possible, and is what I am implementing now as a workaround. But I am looking for a way that does not depend on settings.xml

Comment: @AlexanderWeickmann you can check in doc. It clearly explains how to Manually Overriding the Built-in Repositories. So you can add those repositories either in pox.xml or settings.xml

Comment: Yes that is right. Then my problem in fact boils down to: How to not just overwrite the repositories, but also provide the necessary credentials via pom.xml. The documentation shows how to add <repositories> in either settings.xml or pom.xml. But credentials are given via <servers> in settings.xml and I couldn't find any way to provide them via pom.xml ?

Comment: Right now there is no way to provide <servers> in pom.xml and there are valid reasons why it is not allowed. You can create a custom plugin which will read settings.xml but it is a recommended way. So in your case having the setting in settings.xml would be the only way as per my knowledge

Comment: The best way to handle repositories etc. in Maven is to use the settings.xml. Why is this just a "workaround" for you?

Comment: Because it is unnecessarily complex to get the settings.xml into a cloud build docker container. I had to create this script, which I call at the beginning of my build to inject the credentials into the settings.xml located within the docker container: https://github.com/link-time/docker-atlassian-sdk/blob/master/enable-maven-artifactory.sh

Comment: Injecting the settings.xml via volume is also not an option because in my build system, I can only access files within the Git repository. And I don't want to duplicate settings.xml via many git repositories.